# How to use react-intl with jest

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm working with React Testing Library an I need to get the translation for a text, we mocked  in our setupTest file the react-intl library:

```
jest.mock('react-intl', () => {
  const reactIntl = require.requireActual('react-intl');
  const intl = reactIntl.createIntl({
    locale: 'en'
  });

  return {
    ...reactIntl,
    useIntl: () => intl
  };
});
```

but I don't know how to use it in the test, could someone provide me an complete examble of a test using the library to get a translation, please?
I tried to do it in this way:

```
let intl = useIntl();
      let i18n = {
        header: intl.formatMessage({
          id: 'header.myHeader',
          defaultMessage: 'header.myHeader'
        })
      };
```

but there are any messages in intl from the locales.

Regards.

Answer (score 5):

Don't mock it, try and directly wrap your component with `IntlProvider`, or even better, create a helper `render` where you wrap with `IntlProvider` and render it with that:

```
import {IntlProvider} from 'react-intl`;
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';

const renderWithReactIntl = (component, locale, messages) => {
  return render(<IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
                 {component}
                </IntlProvider>
  );
};
```

Within your `test()` or `it()` just wrap your **unconnected** component in `renderWithReactIntl`:

```
const { /testing library selector goes here/ } 
  = renderWithReactIntl(<YourComponent />, messages, locale)
```

Comment: Thanks, we finally decided to put the text in getByText functions manually instead of get them from the translations.